# How to find dead pixels in android programmatically

Tags: android, pixel

Please guide me, I have a task to write a code that checks the android phone/tablet screen for dead pixels. Is there any API  are provided for this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Not possible. Dead pixels are hardware-related problems which the software cannot detect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no API's that allow you to find dead pixels - after all Android believes that is has asked the display to show a certain color at that point, and it cannot tell that the hardware is actually showing something different. (The screenshot routines, only usable in certain limited circumstances, will likewise not show dead pixels - they show the color that should be there).